# Find the derivative at $x=0$ of $f(x)=x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ where $f(x) = 0$ at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Hey I'm not sure how to start this question so it would be appreciated if someone could please put me in the right direction, thanks!

**Question:**

Find the derivative of the function

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 \sin \left( \frac1x\right), & x \neq 0, \\0, & x=0\end{cases} $$

at $x=0$

I have made attempts at the question however my problem is starting it, as I haven't done a question like this before so a hint would be good, or whatever, if I had working I'd post it, but all i really have is me just differentiating the general function. Anyway, thanks for any help!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the definition of derivative
\begin{align}
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}h\sin\left(\frac{1}{h}\right).
\end{align}

Comment: sorry can you ellaborate! I'm not very familiar with this method! :) Thanks

Comment: I'm applying the standard definition of derivative of a function at a point.

Comment: Okay, so what do you do next? I've never seen this before :/ Thanks :)

Comment: $\lim_{t\to 0} \dfrac{sint}{t}=$?